# How to change current time on a web page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, time

I need to change current time on my web page. How to change it?

I am displaying current time using below code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Digital Clock created with JavaScript" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Current System Time</title>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="not-clock"><span>Current System Time:</span></div>
  <div id="clock"></div>
  <div id="day"></div>
  <div id="date"></div>
  <script src="scriptTime.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Since you have php as a tag, try this: <?php echo date("H:i:s"); ?>

Comment: You asked `How to change it?`-> means you want to show some kind of decreasing timer?

Comment: Use setInterval with an interval of 1 second or 1 minute based on how your clock is made?

Comment: Why don't you show `scriptTime.js` - the essential part of your code? Clarify what you actually are asking or your question will be closed as it is unclear.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone Here it is:

Comment: ```document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
setInterval(function() {
  var currentTime = new Date();

  var hours = currentTime.getHours();
  var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
  var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
  var period = "AM";
  if (hours >= 12) {
    period = "PM";
  }
  if (hours > 12) {
    hours = hours - 12;
  }
  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
  }
  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  } 
  var clockTime = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + period;```

Comment: ``` var clock = document.getElementById('clock');
  clock.innerText = clockTime;
},1000);
});```

Comment: Please use the [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60144854/edit) below your question to improve your question adding formatted code rather than putting it into comments. Further more explain what you exactly mean by 'change time' and point out what your issue is with your approach.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone Say the system time is running as 10:15:30 and having the text box or drop down and update buttons & now I want to change the time as 11:30:20. On filling the time and clicking "update" button, the clock should run as 11:30:21, 11:30:22, 11:30:23,.....

Answer (score 0):

Please set the current time on the web page as per this example.

**HTML**

```
<div class='time-frame'>
    <div id='date-part'></div>
    <div id='time-part'></div>
</div>
<br>
<input type='button' id='stop-interval' value='Stop time' />
```

---

```
**JS**

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            var momentNow = moment();
            $('#date-part').html(momentNow.format('YYYY MMMM DD') + ' '
                                + momentNow.format('dddd')
                                 .substring(0,3).toUpperCase());
            $('#time-part').html(momentNow.format('A hh:mm:ss'));
        }, 100);

        $('#stop-interval').on('click', function() {
            clearInterval(interval);
        });
    });
```

---

```
**CSS**

.time-frame {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 300px;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.time-frame > div {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#date-part {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
#time-part {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```